# Randomly sort rows of Qtablewidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a qtablewidget with some rows. I need to sort these row randomly.

What is the best way to do this ? I have no idea except remove and add all row randomly ...

Comment: Can you clarify if "sort randomly" means sorting by a custom criteria or randomizing the order of items?

Answer (score 0):

**"I assume you are looking for some custom sort. Not column header click sort"**

I have a way to do it. may be much more efficient way will be there.

get the "QList" of "QTableWidgetItem" using below function.

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *>   findItems(const QString & text, Qt::MatchFlags flags) const
```

Then sort your list as shown below with your condiion

```
bool sortFun(const QTableWidgetItem* v1, const QTableWidgetItem* v2)
 {
     return //your sor criteria;
 }

 int doComparison()
 {

     QList<QTableWidgetItem *> fieldsList;

     // Add items to fieldsList.

     qSort(fieldsList.begin(), fieldsList.end(), sortFun);
 }
```

Not clear your "QTableWidget".

Then re assign your sorted list of "QTableWidgetItems" to QTableWidget

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done something different.

What I need to do:
- random the rows of my table
- I have a column with a "Time" and I initialize it with 15:00 for the first row and then add 1 minute for each row.

The solution I used:
- create a qlist with my times (15:00, 15:01, 15:02 ...)
- randomize the qlist (15:01, 15:03, ....)
- assign the qlist's items to the column "Time" of my table
- order my table with the column "Time" with the sort column method.